# Laravel: pagination on $images = json_decode( );

Tags: laravel

I wish to add pagination for my certificates, 8 certs in 1 page. How can I make it? Thanks in advance.

certificates Controller:

```
class certificatesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $currentid = null;
        $certificates = certificates::first();
        $images = json_decode($certificates->image);


        return view('certificate.index', compact('images', 'certificates', 'currentid'));
    }
}
```

index blade:

```
@foreach ($images as $img)
    <div class="grid-item">
        <!-- photo item -->
        <a class="img-box" href="{{ asset('source/upload/certificates/800x600/'.$img) }}">
            <img src="{{ asset('source/upload/certificates/800x600/'.$img) }}" alt="">
        </a></a>
        <!-- end photo item -->
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: $certificates = certificates::paginate(8);

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

Comment: Your question body says you want to paginate your certificates but your question title implies you want to paginate the images. Which one is it?

Comment: Hi, @John Lobo . I used this $certificates = certificates::paginate(8); to solved my problems thank you.

Comment: if the answer from JohnLobo (down below) did the trick for you, please accept it as "The answer" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit number of items in per page in pagination in query then you can pass parameter to paginate() method like below

```
$certificates = certificates::paginate(8);
```

the only argument passed to the paginate method is the number of items you would like displayed `"per page"`. In this case, let's specify that we would like to display `8 items per page`:

In blade template

```
@foreach ($certificates as $certificate)
   
@endforeach
{{ ($certificates->links() }}
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results